# AngularJS Profession/Occupation/Job/Work suggestion in textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

Basically, I want to have a suggestion list for my users for profession/occupation. Now, I could compile a list of all professions in my database table and later display it as a suggestion when a user types the first 2/3 letters of his profession in the textbox. The problem here is I don't want to do all this rather use an API that can provide the list of professions/occupations.

So can I do this? is there any API anyone has used? Or is there a better way?

Here is my code which uses a .csv file link and populates suggestions based on user input, But is there a better way?

**index.html**

```
 <script>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.factory('Items', ['$http', function($http)
    {
        var Url   = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnlsheridan/occupations/master/occupations.csv";
        //var Url =  "file.csv";
        var Items = $http.get(Url).then(function(response)
        {
            return response.data.split('\n');
        });
        return Items;
    }]);

    myApp.controller("MyCtrl", [ "$scope","Items", function ($scope,Items) {
        $scope.fnamequery = '';
        //$scope.fnames = ["Aida", "Aidan", "Alla", "Allen", "Beverly", "Bea", "Caleb","Catherine","false"];
        Items.then(function(data){
            $scope.fnames = data;

            $scope.fnames.shift();
        });
    }]);

</script>
```

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 50%;">
        <input type="text" ng-model="fnamequery">
        <p ng-repeat="fname in fnames | filter:fnamequery track by $index" ng-hide="fnamequery==''">{{fname}}</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```